# What to do when DeviceType gives you the wrong type

Tags: nativescript

On my Huawei tablet, Device.deviceType giving me Phone.

```
this.isTablet = (Device.deviceType === DeviceType.Tablet);
```

My code depends on it. What other way could I detect that it is a table?

I'm using Nativescript 7.

Comment: Generally speaking "Phone" and "Tablet" aren't useful distinctions. What do you actually care about? Display size? Metered bandwidth? Slow network connection? The ability to make voice calls to a regular phone number?

Comment: I'm using a different layout based on screen size. What dimension breakpoints should I use for small to large then?

Comment: Whatever breakpoint suits your designs the best.